# Can not attach file send mail laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, package

My project use Google Mail.
My views:

```
{!! Form::file('fileToUpload') !!}
```

My controller:

```
use Mail;
$input = $request->all();
$data = [
    'confirm' => 'confirm',
    'author' => 'ADMIN',
    'address' => 'mail@mail.com',
    'subject' => 'Send',
    'contents' => 'Hello'];
Mail::send(['view' => 'mail'], $data, function($message) use ($data){
    $message->to($data['address'])
            ->cc($data['address'])
            ->subject($data['subject'])
            ->setBody($data['contents']);
    if(isset($input['fileToUpload'])){
       $message->attach($input['fileToUpload']->getRealPath(),
       array(
           'as' => $input['fileToUpload']->getClientOriginalName(), 
           'mime' => $input['fileToUpload']->getMimeType()));
    }
    $message->from('rootpowercontrol@gmail.com', 'ADMIN');
```

I can send email. But, attached file can not send.
Something went wrong. Anybody help me. Thanks.
Source: https://github.com/HoanNguyenIM/package_mail

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
if ($file = $request->file('fileToUpload')) {
   $message->attach(
       $file->getRealPath(),
       array(
            'as'   => $file->getClientOriginalName(), 
            'mime' => $file->getMimeType()
       )
  );
}
```